# SQLite: Select date and time from (text) date field in Phonegap/Cordova

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I'm creating a Phonegap/Cordova app and have a query about dates in SQLLite.

In one of my tables, I have a date field which I have set to be of the data type 'TEXT' and am storing my dates in the format of `2012-07-21 12:30:00.0000`

Are there any functions I can use in the SELECT statement that will allow me to select just the date or just the time or do I need to extract the whole value and extract the date or time via in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked this out (like a boss).

```
SELECT date(date) as date, time(date) as time FROM ......
```

Easy